# Simple angular example not working: ng-repeat + $resource + GET

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to iterate with ng-repeat, using data served from a REST service. I manage to recover the data in my main.js file, but I can't get the data to be injected into the HTML.

I just started learning nodejs and angular, so it is very probable that I am not clearly getting it. I am logging twice the call to the REST service, getting the data in one of them (using a callback function) and getting a promise in the other (Which I assume happens because the call is synchronous, I didn't use any callback function here).

What I don't understand is why the HTML doesn't get the data.

Anyway, here's the code:

## main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

myApp.factory('restservice', function ($resource) {
    var source = $resource(
        "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting/");
    var data =source.get({},function(){
      //this log shows the data
     console.log (data); 
    })

    return data;
});

function AvengersCtrl($scope, $resource, restservice) {
    $scope.servicedata = restservice;
    //this log shows the promise
    console.log($scope.servicedata);
}
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AngularJS Tutorials</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/foundation/foundation.min.css"> -->
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AvengersCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="resource in servicedata | filter:search">
            <td>{{resource.id}}</td>
            <td>{{resource.content}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular/app/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code looks good to me.

The problem is the service returns a Json object instead of list.

If you wrap it with a list like this, you will see the result

```
$scope.servicedata = [restservice];
```

Comment: Arg. I spent about two hours with this. Thank you very much.